# ping -c1, wait for all responses from broadcast

Tags: networking, ping

I want to send one packet to the broadcast address, but wait for all responses.

If I do `ping -c 1 192.168.1.255`, it sends just one packet, but it quits after getting the first response.

Comment: What do you want to do with that command?

Comment: @Nils: I just want a quick way to see approximately how many hosts are connected to the network. I know about `nmap`, but it has been a bit slow in my experience, compared to `ping`.

Comment: Which version of ping? Even on Linux, there are several around.

Comment: @Gilles: this is the standard `ping` on Mac OS X 10.7.3. I can't seem to find a switch for it to tell its version (tried `-v`, `--version`, searching the man page...).

Comment: Some versions of `ping` have a `-w` option to specify a length of time to wait, regardless of how many reply packets have been received.

Comment: @jw013: just tried it with the `-W` option (`-w` doesn't work with my ping version), and it still quits after the first packet it gets in return.

Comment: @houbysoft That's correct, `-W` is not `-w`: it specifies a timeout and exits with the first packet or when the timeout is reached.

Answer (score 3):

How would `ping` know that the responses it got really are *all of them*?

To find out which hosts on a subnet *are up*, something like [`nmap`](http://nmap.org/) is well suited. [See the `-sn` argument for *Host Discovery*](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html):

> `-sn` (No port scan)
>
> This option tells Nmap not to do a port scan after host discovery, and only print out the available hosts that responded to the scan. This is often known as a “ping scan”,[...]
>
> Systems administrators often find this option valuable as well. It can easily be used to count available machines on a network or monitor server availability. This is often called a ping sweep, and is more reliable than pinging the broadcast address because many hosts do not reply to broadcast queries.

Comment: I don't really care about "all of them", I just need most. Hence I can ping the broadcast and wait for the responses. I understand that ping has no way of knowing when will all responses arrive, but isn't there a way to specify a time for which it should wait?

Comment: For example, I can almost achieve what I want by "ping -c2 -i 10 192.168.1.255". It pings the broadcast and waits 10 seconds for the responses. However, in the end it sends another packet. Is there a way to make it wait 10 seconds, but not send anything afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This quick check for hosts possibly fails nowadays. There is an increasing number of operating systems that blocks incoming ICMP/ping by default. Perhaps there are better - and possibly faster ways to achieve your goal.

If you have SNMP-read-access to the involved router(s) you might get the information (number of hosts in a network) by a simple SNMP-get-request of the corresponding traffic statistic table.

Comment: Is there a standard command that can be used to query this SNMP?

Comment: [Here](http://www.networkuptime.com/tools/netflow/) is a pack of free tools that help to analyse this data.

Comment: Blocking incomming ICMP is a symptom of braindamaged network admin. What most *routers* do nowadays is to just drop any network packet destined to the broadcast address (that was a popular DoS: send something that gives a sizeable response to the broadcast address forging the victim's address and watch it getting bogged down).

Comment: @houbysoft sorry - I forgot to address you directly in my comment.